# HTML / PHP / SQL - Query with parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Here's my code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            Date 1: <input type="text" name="date1">
            Date 2: <input type="text" name="date2">
        </fieldset>
            <button type="submit" name="Search">
    </form>

    <?php
    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "DB is down";
        exit; 
    }

    try {
        $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM instructor WHERE date_hired BETWEEN ? AND ?"); 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "No data found";
        exit;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

    ?>
```

How would I change the PHP code to use the form that I have created to take parameters?

I want to be able to enter 2 dates into the form, so it goes into the query, then output the results.

Comment: You tagged mysqli, but you didn't actually use the mysqli functions. Just so you know where look for the documentation, you're using the PDO abstraction layer, and can read about it at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM instructor WHERE date_hired BETWEEN ? AND ?");
```

to

```
$results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM instructor WHERE date_hired BETWEEN ? AND ?");
$results->execute(array($_POST['date1'], $_POST['date2']));
```

Also, here's a great link to get you started:

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: That's immeasurably better.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Been looking for something like this. I'm getting some errors but i'll check the page and get back to here

Answer (score 1):

When executing statements with placeholders you must give the binding data:

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ... BETWEEN ? AND ?");
$results = $sth->execute(array($start, $end));
```